# Attaching CKEditor to E-mails subject and body?

Tags: wysiwyg, emails

I have installed [**Mime Mail**](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) and am looking at formatting my emails (at admin/config/people/accounts) before sending them to users. How do I attach [**CKEditor**](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) to the E-mail subject and body sections?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no any way to attach it. I used only html tags to format this notifications and their subjects.